# How to navigate controller folder using create URL

Tags: php, ajax, yii2-advanced-app

The controller:

```
controllers
|-SiteAction(folder)
  |-1700(folder)
        |-Participate.php 
|-SiteController
```

How to render Participate.php class using CreateUrl?

```
<?=$this->createUrl('siteActions/1700/participate/'?>
```

is this code write?

Comment: Is this code right

Comment: missing closing `)`